# Why is the polygon not right?

Tags: css, svg

I tried to make an element with the help of `SVG`:

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="200" height="28" viewBox="0 0 200 28">
 <polygon fill='red' stroke='gray' points='0,0 0,170 28,200 0,28z' />
</svg>
```

I need the element to be like below, where is my mistake?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not completely sure about the shape you're aiming for, but I think that for the most part you swapped the order of X and Y coordinates.

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="200" height="28" viewBox="0 0 200 28">
    <polygon fill="red" stroke="gray" points="0,0 170,0 200,28 0,28" />
</svg>
```